# The calling rate of GLSurfaceView.Renderer::onDrawFrame() is too low

Tags: android, opengl-es

I just noticed the strange thing - looks like my GlSurfaceView.Renderer::onDrawFrame() gets called really rarely. At least I'd expect it to be the other way:

Current renderer's renderMode is set to RENDER_CONTINUOUSLY (in fact, i didn't modify the default). By inserting some time measuring code I observe the following:

GLSurfaceView.Renderer::onDrawFrame() is called 100 times in about 15 seconds.
And these 100 frames actually take only about 0.13s to draw.

I wonder where this slowness is coming from and where this 15s-0.13s time is being spent? I would expect the GLSurfaceView to be calling my onDrawFrame like mad, but it looks like it doesn't :)

Am I doing something wrong, or simply I don't know something? Just beginning to learn OpenGL ES...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timing onDrawFrame() is not a reliable way to measure performance. When onDrawFrame() is finished, it does not mean that rendering is finished... it only means you've finished sending commands to the GL. The actual rendering can take a lot more time, and that's probably what you're seeing.

Comment: Hm. Might be the case, didn't think about this. What place would you advice then for measuring FPS? :)

Comment: In the end I made my fps counting code to count fps based on time period instead of adding up time spent in onDrawFrame(). Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: I've been having this same problem, but there has to be something up with this still. We are testing our game on a droid and galax s device. on the high res on the droid we run into this exact issue, we try locking the frames at 30fps, however on the calls between on draw frame take 30-60 ms however, at the lower res, everything is smooth. We find it hard to believe that the difference between 800x400 and 533x320 is so big that it causes this issue. And we even have tested with drawing nearly nothing to screen. However, games like angry birds and glow hockey manage to not lag at all ont he dro